PayPal documentation always tell to use Node.js, but there is a client-only script that works even better
For PayPal integration all their documentation tells you to call server-side script running on Node.js, and here the client-side call to the CreateOrder function in the server:
        async createOrder() {
                const response = await fetch("/api/orders", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        cart: [
                            {
                                id: "NQ888P",
                                quantity: "3",
                            },
                        ],
                    }),
                });

But there is not a single document on this much better alternative: The code below, 100% running from client, does not call any server-side script at all. It goes straight to PayPal's site and does the same or even better job than the mechanism above:
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            intent: 'CAPTURE',
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: "14.99",
                    currency_code: "USD"
                }
            }]
        })
    },

This code can only be found in stackoverflow and other forums. So does anyone know why PayPal suppresses the client-only mechanism from all the documents?

It's documented right here, and appears to be part of PayPal's alternative payment method (APM) SDK, which is not regular PayPal.

Man! this is the best information hiding ever! Not even Microsoft hides cheats that well. *** Marked as the correct answer.

That is an old document that has not been updated to remove what is a deprecated integration method due to be sunset.

The client-side-only method is deprecated and PayPal has notified those using it that support will be sunset in the future. Do not use it for any purpose.
The method of creating and capturing via API is the only supported one. The node.js samples are examples, and the same functionality can be implemented with any server environment that is not node.
